# JQuery Populate Dropdown by Attribute of tr tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I failed to populate dropdownbox according to my need (the AJAX is working). That is it will take value from 'number' attribute from  tag and pass it to a function.

I want to take the attribute 'number' from  tag because later on I will add and delete this  tag dynamically with JQuery(for multiple vehicle).

***The problem is the dropdown kept resetting as I click the dropdown, how to overcome this problem?***

This is my JQuery Code:

```
var counterVehicle = 0;  
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "tr.vehicle" ).click(function(e) {
        counterVehicle = $(this).attr('number');
        VehicleCategory();
    }); 

    //Start Vehicle
    $("#category" + counterVehicle).change(function(){
        var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
        VehicleBrand(category);
    });

    $("#brand"  + counterVehicle).change(function(){
        var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
        var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
        VehicleModel(category,brand);
    });

    $("#model" + counterVehicle).change(function(){
        var category=$(".category").val();
        var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
        var model=$("#model" + counterVehicle).val();
        VehicleYear(category,brand,model);
    });

    $("#year" + counterVehicle).change(function(){
        var category=$(".category").val();
        var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
        var model=$("#model" + counterVehicle).val();
        var year=$("#year" + counterVehicle).val();
        VehicleMileage(category,brand,model,year);
    });

    $("#mileage" + counterVehicle).change(function(){
        var category=$(".category").val();
        var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
        var model=$("#model" + counterVehicle).val();
        var year=$("#year" + counterVehicle).val();
        var mileage=$("#mileage" + counterVehicle).val();
        VehiclePrice(category,brand,model,year,mileage);
    });

});
```

This my HTML Code for this dropdown :

```
<tr class="vehicle" number="1">
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td><select id="category1" class="form-control category"></select></td>
    <td><select id="brand1" class="form-control brand"></select></td>
    <td><select id="model1" class="form-control model"></select></td>
    <td><select id="year1" class="form-control year"></select></td>
    <td><select id="mileage1" class="form-control mileage"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="price1" class="form-control price" disabled></td>
</tr> 

<tr class="vehicle" number="2">
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td><select id="category2" class="form-control category"></select></td>
    <td><select id="brand2" class="form-control brand"></select></td>
    <td><select id="model2" class="form-control model"></select></td>
    <td><select id="year2" class="form-control year"></select></td>
    <td><select id="mileage2" class="form-control mileage"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="price2" class="form-control price" disabled></td>
</tr>
```

This is the picture of the HTML:

[image]

Comment: Are you missing out on closing the `tr` tag?

Comment: No, I'm not (in my source code). The problem is on the algorithm of jquery.

Comment: @SkyvrawleR as there are better ways to write this... but regardless of that, how are you incrementing counterVehicle, I get the feeling either you are not or you are repeating lots of similar code...

Comment: @Seabizkit care to show me the way? Currently repeating lots of similar code with JQuery.

Comment: @SkyvrawleR i suggest you ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Seabizkit Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129125/jquery-ajax-dropdown-repeatedly-reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The problem is the dropdown kept resetting as I click the dropdown, how to overcome this problem?***

You have to stop the `click` event to bubble up at `tr` with `event.stopPropagation();` because when you apply a `change` event on any dropdown it will propagate the click event **first** to the closest `tr` and thus `VehicleCategory()` executes and resets.:

```
var counterVehicle = 0;  
$(document).ready(function(){

        $( "tr.vehicle" ).click(function(e) {
            counterVehicle = $(this).attr('number');
            VehicleCategory(); // <----this gets executed when you try to apply change
        });                    // event on any dropdown because you click before change.


        //Start Vehicle
        $("#category" + counterVehicle).change(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
            VehicleBrand(category);
        });

        $("#brand"  + counterVehicle).change(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
            var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
            VehicleModel(category,brand);
        });

        $("#model" + counterVehicle).change(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
            var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
            var model=$("#model" + counterVehicle).val();
            VehicleYear(category,brand,model);
        });

        $("#year" + counterVehicle).change(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
            var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
            var model=$("#model" + counterVehicle).val();
            var year=$("#year" + counterVehicle).val();
            VehicleMileage(category,brand,model,year);
        });

        $("#mileage" + counterVehicle).change(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var category=$("#category" + counterVehicle).val();
            var brand=$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).val();
            var model=$("#model" + counterVehicle).val();
            var year=$("#year" + counterVehicle).val();
            var mileage=$("#mileage" + counterVehicle).val();
            VehiclePrice(category,brand,model,year,mileage);
        });

    });
```