# JQuery AJAX Dropdown Repeatedly Reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

From this question : [JQuery Populate Dropdown by Attribute of tr tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123405/jquery-populate-dropdown-by-attribute-of-tr-tag)

***Is there another way to accomplish this? I can't find the algorithm behind this***

JQuery Code VehicleCategory():

```
function VehicleCategory(){

            $("#category" + counterVehicle).empty();
            $("#category" + counterVehicle).append("<option>Loading.....</option>");
            $("#brand"  + counterVehicle).append("<option value=''>-Select Brand-</option>");
            $("#model" + counterVehicle).append("<option value=''>-Select Model-</option>");
            $("#year" + counterVehicle).append("<option value=''>-Select Year-</option>");
            $("#mileage" + counterVehicle).append("<option value=''>-Select Mileage-</option>");
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"car_dropdown.php?comboBoxName=category",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#category" + counterVehicle).empty();
                    $("#category" + counterVehicle).append("<option value=''>-Select Category-</option>");
                    $.each(data,function(i,item){
                         $("#category" + counterVehicle).append('<option value="'+ data[i].category +'">'+ data[i].category +'</option>');
                    });

                },

                complete: function(){

                }

            });
        }
```

When I load the page:
[image]

When I click the first dropdown:
[image]

When I click the dropdown again and again ^^':
[image]

Comment: Elaborate a little more as just the images themselves can't state everything. Meanwhile show us the code that _calls_ your `VehicleCategory()` function.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri its from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123405/jquery-populate-dropdown-by-attribute-of-tr-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the VehicleCategory() multiple times.. If you need to do this, then empty the prior contents..

change..

```
$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).append("<option value=''>-Select Brand-</option>");
```

to:

```
$("#brand"  + counterVehicle).html("<option value=''>-Select Brand-</option>");
```

Comment: That is just one part of the problem. How to populate all data into dropdown?